# HTML png background

Tags: html, css, png

[image: Car]

I want to use this image (or any other) in a school project but I want those gray and white squares to dissapear and only have the car.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color : #000;}
  
  #div{
   background : url('https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171201/41c/mercedes-benz-png-file-5a21ecfdce9485.7702393815121727978462.jpg') no-repeat;
   background-size : cover;
   height : 500px;
   width : 500px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find anything specific about this problem because I don't what is the actual question to ask.

Comment: JPG supports no transparency. GIF supports limited transparency (either not-transparent or fully transparent). What you need is PNG, because it supports semi-transparency. Try replacing your image with this: https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/car/4-2-car-png-hd.png and the rest of your code should be ok.

Comment: The squares are on the original image - you need to find an image without them (that you have permission to use) - they are usually put on so people don't steel them and reuse them without permission (seems to be what you are trying to do).  As it is an image problem - you probably want to ask design stack exhange how to remove them from the image using whatever image editor you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is a jpg, which doesn't support transparency.
You need to export your image as PNG in order to get transparency working

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you need to use a PNG image file. Do not get the jpg image you have now and convert to PNG as it will not work.